# Undefined index when uploading image

Tags: php, image-upload

I am trying to create a form for user to upload image by using php.

here is my input file:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="imageToUpload" id="imageToUpload"> 
</form>
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
    $file_up_size = $_FILES["imageToUpload"]["size"];
?>
```

error -> Notice: Undefined index: imageToUpload ...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form was sent, then work with variable.

```
if (isset($_FILES["imageToUpload"])) {
    $file_up_size = $_FILES["imageToUpload"]["size"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$myImage = getimagesize($_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name']);
if ($myImage !== false) {
    // Process image further
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the code suggested in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). They are using the PHP [function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.getimagesize.php) `getimagesize`

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```